# smartgwt remove duplicate values from selectitem

Tags: smartgwt

Does anybody know how to hide duplicate values (course names) from `SelectItem`?

My code:

```
SelectItem  courseOfferingItem = new SelectItem ("courseOffering.id", "Course Offering");
courseOfferingItem.setOptionDataSource(CoursesOfferingDS.getInstance());
courseOfferingItem.setDisplayField("courseOffering.courseName");
courseOfferingItem.setShowDisabled(false);
```

`SelectItem` is showing courses CBNST, FIT, FIT, DS but I don't want to show FIT two times.

Answer (score 0):

you must use LinkedHashMap to populate your ComboBox items. it will be easy to set and manage and duplicate values will be removed. it can be done by....
SelectItem courseOfferingItem = new SelectItem();
courseOfferingItem.setValueMap(linedHashMap);

and linkedHashMap will contain your item id and item value...hope it will be useful to you...